# Is it possibly to modify the request before being processed by the routes file in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Is it possibly to modify the request before being processed by the routes file?

Basically the app I am looking to build will have hundreds of slug URLs. But the slugs will lead to different controllers. To achieve this I will keep key:values pairs in redis.

For example:

```php
// slug = domain.com/slug-one
// Would route to
Route::get('pages/{id}', 'PagesController@index');

// slug = domain.com/slug-two
// Would route to
Route::get('articles/{id}', 'ArticlesController@index');
```

For me the best way would be to modify the request in the before filter in filters.php

```php
App::before(function($request)
{
    // Do Redis Lookup.  If match change request path
    $request->path = "$controller/$id";
});
```

Hope you can advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change a request routes in a filter because filters are applied AFTER the route is resolved.

One way would be to define a route like that:

```php
Route::get('/{$request}', 'PagesController@slugRedirect');
```

Then inside the slugRedirect you do your redis lookup then call (or redirect with 301) the correct controller like that:

```php
// Create a new separate request
$request = Request::create('/articles/1', 'GET');
// Dispatch the new request to a new route
$response = Route::dispatch($request);
// Fetch the response (in your case, return it)
```

I haven't tested that, please let me know if it work or not.

Comment: No thats no good at all. Basically the slugs would all being redirects is not want I want at all. Changing the path is what I need to do.

Comment: That's why I sayd you can call the correct controller with the correct parameters (so there is no redirect for the user). I've added some info on why you can't change the route inside a filter.

Comment: I didn't know the Route::dispatch so TY. While I like Laravel the Docs are a little on the slim side.