# How to forward a request with parameters/arguments to a different URL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am working on a system that receives a request to a URL and forwards the request to a different URL after performing some actions (not relevant for the question). Example: The system receives a GET request to `http://localhost/users/123/my/path?foo=1&bar=abc` and then forward the user to `http://localhost/my/path?foo=1&bar=abc` using GET as well. Getting the new path and arguments is not a problem.

Using [redirects](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/redirects) works perfectly when there are no arguments. However, I need to keep all the request data, like method name (GET, POST, etc) and arguments, which does not work with the `redirect($newRoute)`. According to Laravel documentation and some experiments I tried, `redirect($newRoute)->whith($params)` works only for URL parameters, like `http://localhost/{$id}/some/path`, but not for `http://localhost/some/path?id=456`, for example.

I also tried creating a new request based in the old one. It works fine except for one essential detail: the URL in the browser remains the old one. Exemple: when requesting `http://localhost/users/123/my/path?foo=1&bar=abc`, the system behaves as expected but stays in the same URL, not the right one (`http://localhost/my/path?foo=1&bar=abc`). It is a requirement that the system return/go to the new URL. I create the new request like this, as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351697/is-it-possibly-to-modify-the-request-before-being-processed-by-the-routes-file-i):

```
$newRequest = Request::create("/" . $newRoute, $originalRequest->getMethod(), $originalRequest->all());
return Route::dispatch($newRequest);
```

Any thoughts on how can I accomplish what I need?

Thanks guys!

Comment: did you try to redirect it with native php header function? like `header("Location: yourUrl".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']); `

Comment: @devnullΨ, I did not, but after digging a bit more on internet and with the answer provided below, I was able to solve my problem. Thank you for your comment, though.

Comment: Why was my question down voted? Provide some feedback so I can do something about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:
return redirect()->away('https://localhost/my/path?foo='.$foo.'&bar='.$bar.');

[Redirecting to External Domains (Laravel)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/responses#redirecting-external-domains)

Comment: I used your answer to build a redirect command using Laravel `URL::to()` and php [http_built_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) functions. So, I got it with `redirect()->away(URL::to("/$newPath?") . http_build_query($request->all()))`.


Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25765874/how-to-redirect-a-named-route-with-querystring-in-laravel-4-2) is for Laravel 4.2 but works too for Laravel 5.4 too.